# AOP logging of stored proc calls

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, logging, aop, jdbctemplate

I have inherited large complex Web App which includes Flex/Robotlegs, BlazeDS and Spring3.
It makes many calls to DB Stored Procs (SQL Server) using Spring's `JdbcTemplate` and `SimpleJdbcCall` - like:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.jdbcTemplate)
    .withProcedureName(someproc)
    .returningResultSet("getsomedata", BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(SomeBean.class));
```

Tracing every DB call through >10 layers is painfull.

It would greatly help to implement logging of those StoredProcs calls using Spring AOP (log Stored Proc name and input params), I just have no experience with it.

TIA,
Oleg.

Comment: Can you be specific, what is the question? Is it how to implement logging through all those layers?

Comment: do you maybe need any code sample for AOP logging in spring?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to get a sample code showing how to implement that in Spring3.  I only need to log calls to that SimpleJdbcCall class methods (printing out stored proc name and params).

Comment: Please help me to get started with that code...      Or would it make more sense / be easier to use Craftsman Spy framework for that: https://dzone.com/articles/logging-spring-jdbc-and